# Получение ссылки на вложение VK API

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

В событии от имени пользователя, в сообщении приходит только такой словарь с вложениями:

```
{'attach1_type': 'photo', 'attach1': '281235057_457241035'}
```

Проблема в том, что тут не имеется прямой ссылки для вложения, чтобы его можно было скачать. Каким другим образом её можно получить?

Answer (score 0):

В словаре хранится тип вложения и его уникальный id. Для того, что бы получить полную информацию об вложении (где можно получить прямую ссылку), необходимо сделать запрос к VK api. К примеру, для фотографии: [photos.getById](https://vk.com/dev/photos.getById), а для видео: [video.get](https://vk.com/dev/video.get).